# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot bind argument at index 2 because the index is out of range

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

When I run emulator it show unfortunately,Parkit has stopped. 
I'm getting the following error, and I have no idea why it is occurring. I was wondering if anyone else might be able to shed some light on the issue.
Please help.

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot bind argument at index 2 because the index is out of range.  The statement has 0 parameters.
```

code here:

```
package com.example.a.parkit;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
SQLiteDatabase db;
SQLiteOpenHelper openHelper;
Button btnlogin, btnsigup;
EditText loguname, logpass;
Cursor cursor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btnlogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnlogin);
    btnsigup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnpass);
    loguname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loguname);
    logpass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.logpass);
    openHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    db = openHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    btnlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String username =loguname.getText().toString();
            String pass =logpass.getText().toString();
            cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT *FROM " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + DatabaseHelper.COL_2 + "='?' AND " + DatabaseHelper.COL_4 + "='?' ", new String[]{username, pass});
            if (cursor != null) {
                if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MapsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    btnsigup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SignUp.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Is there a missing space in `SELECT *FROM`?

Comment: Moreover, these **parameters** `'?'` go **without** `'`. *5 errors in a single line*. That's actually a ***Guinness World Record***!

Answer (score 1):

The error that you get is because you have enclosed the 2 bind specifiers, the **`?`**'s in single quotes **`'`** thus the 2 **`?`**'s are not recognised as bind specifiers.

However, correcting this on it's own would result in the query then failing because you haven't separated the keyword SELECT from the column specifier the **`*`**.

I believe that using the following will correct the errors :-

```
cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + 
    DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME + 
    " WHERE " + DatabaseHelper.COL_2 + "=? AND " + DatabaseHelper.COL_4 + "=? ", 
    new String[]{username, pass}
);
```

You follow this with `if (cursor != null)` this will do nothing and is useless as a returned cursor from any of the SQLiteDatabase methods (`rawQuery` in this instance) will never be null.

Additionally you should always close a Cursor when done with it.

I'd suggest that you should have/use :-

```
btnlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String username =loguname.getText().toString();
        String pass =logpass.getText().toString();
        cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + 
            DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME + 
            " WHERE " + DatabaseHelper.COL_2 + "=? AND " + DatabaseHelper.COL_4 + "=? ", 
            new String[]{username, pass}
        );
        int rowcount = cursor.getCount(); //<<<< ADDED to get row count
        cursor.close(); //<<<< ADDED to close the Cursor
        if (rowcount > 0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MapsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
```

---

If you used the ***recommended*** SQLiteDatabase `query` method, the code could instead be :-

```
btnlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String username =loguname.getText().toString();
        String pass =logpass.getText().toString();
        cursor = db.query(
            DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME,
            null, // (all columns)
            DatabaseHelper.COL_2 + "=? AND " + DatabaseHelper.COL_4 + "=?",
            new String[]{username, pass},
            null, null, null 
        );
        int rowcount = cursor.getCount(); //<<<< ADDED to get row count
        cursor.close(); //<<<< ADDED to close the Cursor
        if (rowcount > 0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MapsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
```

[SQLiteDatabase - query](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html)

- Note there are 4 different query methods each with subtly different signatures. The above uses the 4th.

Comment: thank you. Its work fine

Comment: @arnabdas That's good. Please tick the question as answered.